# Default image for ipad not showing

Tags: objective-c

I have made universal app so i have 2 default images one for ipad and another for iphone while running the app the ipad is taking the iphone default.png for display but the iphone default image is showing properly.how to display the default.png for ipad.The default images name i have given are for iphone default.png and for ipad default-Ipad.png.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](http://phunkwerk.posterous.com/ipad-managing-multiple-launch-images-aka-defa) you need Default-LandscapeRight, Default-LandscapeLeft etc etc...